# Flutter : primaryColorLight != null': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart

I need a custom color theme for my app. So I defined a Material Color in **MyTheme.dart** as follows.

```
 static const int _bluePrimaryValue = 0xFF2D9CDB;
  static const MaterialColor blue = MaterialColor(
    _bluePrimaryValue,
    <int, Color>{
      200: Color(0xFF6EBBE6),
      300: Color(0xFF59B1E2),
      400: Color(0xFF43A6DF),
      500: Color(_bluePrimaryValue),
      600: Color(0xFF238FCC),
      700: Color(0xFF1F7FB6),
      800: Color(0xFF1B70A0),
      900: Color(0xFF0D47A1),
    },
  );
```

In my Material App, I replaced

```
  child: MaterialApp(
..
                theme:
                    ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue, fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
  ..)
```

with

```
 child: MaterialApp(
    ..
                    theme:
                        ThemeData(primarySwatch: MyTheme.blue, fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
      ..)
```

the primarySwatch accepts a MaterialColor parameter and Colors.blue and MyTheme.blue are of the same Type. But there is no error when giving Colors.blue but the following error arise when giving MyTheme.blue.

> Failed assertion: line 525 pos 15: 'primaryColorLight != null': is not
> true.

This is solved when giving **primaryColorLight** parameter in MaterialApp's theme attribute. But why this error is not arising when using Colors.blue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because ThemeData class sets primaryColorLight from the primarySwatch you gave.

```
primaryColorLight ??= isDark ? Colors.grey[500] : primarySwatch[100];
```

Colors.blue which is the default Colors provided by Flutter provide variations ranging from 50 - 900. The following is the definition of **Colors.blue**

```
static const MaterialColor blue = MaterialColor(
    _bluePrimaryValue,
    <int, Color>{
      50: Color(0xFFE3F2FD),
      100: Color(0xFFBBDEFB),
      200: Color(0xFF90CAF9),
      300: Color(0xFF64B5F6),
      400: Color(0xFF42A5F5),
      500: Color(_bluePrimaryValue),
      600: Color(0xFF1E88E5),
      700: Color(0xFF1976D2),
      800: Color(0xFF1565C0),
      900: Color(0xFF0D47A1),
    },
  );
  static const int _bluePrimaryValue = 0xFF2196F3;
```

But the MyTheme.blue doesn't have the color corresponding to shade 100.